# SQL Server over order by with predefined order

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I have query with simple order:

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY flagid desc ) as RowNr,
    stepid, flagid
FROM
(
select stepid, flagid
from opstep_flag
where stepid = 262677032
) a
```

And It returns data like this:

[image]

It is possible to order data that the flagid will be for example 7,5,8 ?

I want to define somewhere that flagid 7 is first, flagid 5 is second and flagid 8 is third. Now I can only change order with asc or desc and 5,7,8 I can change to 8,7,5. But I need to have 7,5,8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `ORDER BY` with [`CASE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) expression as below:

```
 ORDER BY (CASE flagid WHEN 7 THEN 1 WHEN 5 THEN 2 WHEN 8 THEN 3 ELSE 4 END)
```

Comment: `case` _expression_.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `CASE` expression in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
ORDER BY CASE flagid 
          WHEN 7 THEN 1 
          WHEN 5 THEN 2 
          WHEN 8 THEN 3 
          ELSE 4 
        END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case`, but I find that a derived table might be more easily maintained and debugged:

```
select stepid, flagid,
       row_number() over (order by v.ord) as rownr
from opstep_flag f left join
     (values (1, 7), (2, 5), (3, 8)
     ) v(ord, flagid)
     on f.flagid = v.flagid
where f.stepid = 262677032;
```

Note that if you have a canonical ordering, you can maintain that in the reference table that `flagid` refers to.

Also, a subquery/CTE is not necessary for this query.

Answer (score 0):

To Answer your question more generally (because I think there's another data hiding behind your question), suppose you have another table  (table new_order) with values

```
FlagId NewFlagOrder
1       7
2       5
3       8
```

use

```
SELECT
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY flagid desc ) as RowNr,
stepid, flagid

FROM
(
select o.stepid, new_order.NewFlagOrder as flagid
from opstep_flag o RIGHT JOIN
     new_order ON o.flagid = new_order.FlagId
where stepid = 262677032
) a
```